# jq cast result into bash array

Tags: json, bash, jq

next to my attempt to parse a JSON response from curl using bash I now decided to give a try with jq.
I have checked the documentation but I could not find a way to iterate trough the elements and "do" something.

Here's an idea on what I am trying to achieve, cast the result from jq into an array, (it doesn't work)

```
__json=$($omd_response | ~/local-workspace/bash/jq -r '[.]')
for x in "${__json[@]}"
do
  echo "-metadata" $x
done
```

Any other idea is much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Can you provide some input and expected output?

Comment: `array=( $(...) )` is generally speaking an antipattern. Even when you set `IFS` you get undesired behaviors.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/630274/42620 for a way to convert a json array to a bash array, then use normal shell looping.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
declare -a things
things=($(jq tostring myfile.json) )
for x in "${things[@]}"; do
    echo "-metadata" "$x"
done
```

almost works.  It splits things on whitespace.

This works:

```
declare -a things
OIFS=$IFS
IFS= things=($(jq -r 'tojson|tostring' myfile.json) )
IFS=$OIFS
for x in "${things[@]}"; do
    echo "-metadata" "$x"
done
```

Really, we need a JSON-aware shell...  Something like ksh93's compound variables, but JSON-compatible.

Comment: If one of your strings was `*`, you'd get a list of filenames in your array. That doesn't happen when you're reading strings into bash [in accordance with best practices](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).